# Select all but the most recent row in a database using Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to select all rows from a mysql table except for the most recent one by using Eloquent in Laravel.
I currently do this to get the most recent entry only, but wish to do the reverse:

```
Table::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Any idea how I do this?

Comment: so would you say you want to skip one record and take the rest in this order?

Comment: @lagbox yeah that is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of laravel collections shift method.

```
$data = DB::table('your_table')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
$data->shift(); //which removes the first element. now $data has all other values except for first one.
```

Answer (score 3):

you can simply [skip](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#skip-take) the first one from the results:

```
Table::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(1)->get();
```

Comment: this is more accurate